# How to get raster metadata use Geotools just as gdalinfo do?

Tags: gdal, geotools

Is there anyway to get raster file's metadata, such as pixel size and nodata value of a GeoTIFF file, use GeoTools in a Java program?

Now, I can get the Coordinate Reference System and Envelope's coordinates, but don't know how to get full metadata just as gdal's gdalinfo function does.

GDAL's Java bindings API is not convenient during deployment.

Comment: You need to explain more - are you trying to do this from a programming language, an operating system shell, or somewhere else? Please edit your question with some more information.

Comment: which metadata do you need?

Comment: @IanTurton basically  are nodata value, epsg, PixelSize and basic statistics

Answer (score 2):

I used following code to get those metadata (nodata value, epsg, PixelSize and basic statistics) I want:

```
//get nodata
double nodata = CoverageUtilities.getNoDataProperty(coverage).getAsSingleValue();
//get epsg code
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = coverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
CRS.lookupEpsgCode(crs, true); 
//PixelSize Y
RenderedImage image = coverage.getRenderedImage();
(envelope2D.getMaxY() - envelope2D.getMinY()) / image.getHeight();
//get statistics
CoverageClassStats rasterProcess = new CoverageClassStats();
Set<Statistic> set = new HashSet();
set.add(Statistic.MAX);
set.add(Statistic.MIN);
set.add(Statistic.MEAN);
set.add(Statistic.SDEV);
CoverageClassStats.Results results = rasterProcess.execute(coverage, set, 0, 1, ClassificationMethod.QUANTILE, nodata, null);
results.value(0, Statistic.MIN);// get min
```